# How to decrypt a homomorphically modified ciphertext in Elgamal cryptosystem?

Tags: elgamal-encryption

From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption), we know that to encrypt a message $M$ using Elgmal encryption, one should firstly map the message $M$ to an element $m$ of G using a reversible mapping function, then run the ElGamal encryption algorithm to get the ciphertext $C$. To decrypt $C$, one should run the decryption algorithm to get $m$, and finally, map the $m$ back to $M$ using a reversible mapping function.

As we know that Elgamal encryption is also a multiplicative holomorphic encryption scheme. My question is how to decrypt a homomorphically modified ciphertext? For example, now I have two ciphertexts, $C_1,C_2$, encrypting $M_1, M_2$ respectively with the same recipient public key. I compute $C^{\prime}=C_1C_2$. CanI decrypt $C^{\prime}$ to get the message $M_1\times M_2$ using a reversible mapping function? If we can, what is the reversible mapping function? Thanks!

Comment: @knaccc Yes, the same recipient public key. I am looking to encrypt message from $Z_p$.

Comment: What I mean by $Z_p$ is just the order of the group. I don't mean the order of the underlying finite field(i.e., the order of the x-coordinate). To avoid confusion, let me denote the order of the underlying finite field $Z_q$.

Comment: Yes, I am just wondering if it is possible to make a homomorphic reversible mapping function to achieve my goal?

Comment: If not, then what is the point of the multiplicative homomorphic property of Elgamal? Doesn't it just mean enc(m1)enc(m2)=enc(m1m2)?

Comment: It will not give $(m_1+m_2) mod \ell$, but $m_1\times m_2 mod \ell$ because of the multiplicative homomorphic property, rather than additive holomorphic one.

Comment: Do you mean we can achieve my goal with the help of commitment?

Comment: ok, I get it.  Thanks.

Comment: Btw my comments were about EC El Gamal, and I only meant to indicate that what you are describing isn't possible with the EC variant. I haven't thought through the implications of the regular version as described in wikipedia. I was confused as to which variant you were referring to, and I'm still not sure since you've mentioned x-coordinates.

Comment: ok, I see. Thank you anyway!